# Установить прокси для модема на C# (через реестр)

Tags: c#, реестр, прокси, модемы

Всем здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста как на C# установить прокси не для локальной сети, а для модема.

Для локальной сети делаю так:

```
string proxy = "144.217.174.12:8888";
RegistryKey reg_key;
reg_key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
reg_key.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
reg_key.SetValue("ProxyServer", proxy);
```

В настройках браузера в результате:

[image]

В реестре в разделе `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`:

[image]

Как мне сделать тоже самое только для настроек не локальной сети, а модема?Наверное есть раздел реестра, который отвечает за модемы,подскажите его пожалуйста, потому что код вроде бы будет такой же. Или поправьте,если я что-то не так думаю.
То есть здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мониторил кучу действий, который браузер делает в реестре, при подключении прокси к модему через окно, удалось выделить следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код на C# работы с InternetSetOption

```
 class Program
{
    public struct Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
    {
        public int dwAccessType;
        public IntPtr proxy;
        public IntPtr proxyBypass;
    }

    [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet,int dwOption,IntPtr lpBuffer,int lpdwBufferLength);

    private static void RefreshIESettings(string strProxy)
    {
        const int INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY = 38;
        const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY = 3;

        Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO struct_IPI;

        struct_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY;
        struct_IPI.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy);
        struct_IPI.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local");

        IntPtr intptrStruct = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, true);
        InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI));
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RefreshIESettings("203.142.34.36:52335");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Никогда не задумывался над модемами, но могу порекомендовать способ как узнать самостоятельно: используйте программы для мониторинга изменений в реестре. Запустили, сделали какое-либо изменение в настройках модема, сравнили разницу. RegMon, RegShot и тому подобные.

Comment: @AK Спасибо за совет. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: @AK Не знаю те ли действия я выделил в RegMon, потому что там их тысячи после одного только клика на ОК. Но вроде бы оно. Для определенного модема он вставляет в буфер значений-ip:port прокси.
Вопрос теперь в том, а как мне в программе сделать это для одного модема вообще и для всех подключенных модемов,как думаете?
Для 1 модема я так понимаю: обращаться к полю реестра "Значение" и в определенные позиции вписывать значения прокси в 16-м виде?!

Comment: Для одного модема используйте код, как вы привели в самом начале вопроса. А вот для все модемов нужно будет научиться получать список модемов в системе, а потом для каждого в цикле устанавливать настройки. То есть нет общих для всех модемов, только для каждого индивидуально задавать.

Comment: См. также: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/226473/how-to-programmatically-query-and-set-proxy-settings-under-internet-ex

Comment: @AK хорошо, но вот только как применить этот код для одного модема, если в реестре для настройки модема нет таких полей, как: proxy enable и server. Для модема одна большая область с 16ми значениями.

Comment: @VadimTagil спасибо за наводки, сейчас буду разбираться.

Comment: @VadimTagil библиотека для C++. Нашел реализацию на C# [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353715/how-do-i-use-internetsetoption)
Пробую тестировать, никакой реакции, ничего не изменяется. Кароче сходу взять не получилось, сейчас буду вникать в параметры.

Comment: @VadimTagil посмотрите пожалуйста на код (добавил сверху), может у вас получится сразу увидеть ошибку.

Comment: INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY - это для локальной сети. Для dial up подключений нужен INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать функцию [InternetSetOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa385114(v=vs.85).aspx) с параметром `INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION`. Для получения необходимого результата нужно установить две опции: `INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER` - имя прокси-сервера и `INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS` - флаг, указывающий на использование явно заданного прокси-сервера. Затем нужно обновить настройки IE с помощью вызова `InternetSetOption` с параметром `INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace InternetTest
{
    public class Internet
    {        
        public const uint INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION = 75;
        public const uint INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37;
        public const uint INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS = 1;
        public const uint INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER = 2;
        public const uint PROXY_TYPE_PROXY = 0x00000002;        

        [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, uint
        dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);

        /*Установка значения прокси-сервера strProxy для подключения strCon*/
        public static bool SetProxy(string strCon,string strProxy)
        {
            InternetPerConnOptionList optlist = new InternetPerConnOptionList();
            IntPtr pstruct = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(optlist));
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION opt = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
            bool res;

            try
            {
                // proxy server   
                optlist.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(InternetPerConnOptionList));
                optlist.szConnection = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(strCon);
                optlist.dwOptionCount = 1;
                optlist.options = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(opt));
                opt.dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;
                opt.Value = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(strProxy);

                Marshal.StructureToPtr(opt, optlist.options, true);
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(optlist, pstruct, true);

                res = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION,
                    pstruct, Marshal.SizeOf(optlist));
                if (res == false) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Failed to set proxy server");

                //flags
                INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION2 opt2 = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION2();
                opt2.dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
                opt2.Value = PROXY_TYPE_PROXY;
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(opt2, optlist.options, true);

                res = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION,
                    pstruct, Marshal.SizeOf(optlist));
                if (res == false) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Failed to set flags");

                //refresh
                res = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH,
                    IntPtr.Zero, 0);
                if (res == false) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Failed to refresh IE settings");
            }
            finally
            {                
                if (opt.Value != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(opt.Value); 
                if (optlist.options != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(optlist.options);
                if(optlist.szConnection!=IntPtr.Zero)Marshal.FreeHGlobal(optlist.szConnection);
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pstruct);
            }

            return res;
        }

    }    

    /* СТРУКТУРЫ */

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct InternetPerConnOptionList
    {        
        public int dwSize;        
        public IntPtr szConnection;        
        public int dwOptionCount;        
        public int dwOptionError;
        public IntPtr options;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION //первый вариант структуры (для указателя)
    {
        public uint dwOption;
        public IntPtr Value;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION2 //второй вариант структуры (для DWORD)
    {
        public uint dwOption;
        public uint Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает!)